# Compiling frameworks(cppunit, boost, ++) from terminal to work with Xcode 4.6

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, compiler-construction, linker

I'm trying to use some frameworks with Xcode 4.6.2.
C++ frameworks, such as cppunit and boost that is supposed to be compiled and linked to in my projects always fails with "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64[...]" or i386 for that matter when I'm trying different build settings.

I have tried setting Compiler to clang and g++ with various sets of cpu-architecture flags (64, 32 and 32_64). I have come to a point where I can't find any solutions on my own.

I've also tried the fail safe packages from without any luck:
brew install cppunit universal
port install cppunit +universal
(Also without success the Boost library)

Also, a lot of tries on Boost is done. Bjam has really made a lot of work the last 24 hours. Multiple settings has been tried:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/555070/Boost-vs-OSX-iOS-XCode 
 and
http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Errors-compiling-Boost-Log-on-OS-X-tp4646151p4646299.html 
And more in pure trial and error on my part.

So my question is: what are the combination of compiler and linker and the respective flags I should use in order to make it work in my Xcode projects?

Per request from Captain Obvlious, here are some errors when running an application with Boost::Test:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_impl(boost::test_tools::predicate_result const&, boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level, boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type, unsigned long, ...)", referenced from:
      my_test::test_method() in main.o
  "boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::set_checkpoint(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, unsigned long, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)", referenced from:
      my_test::test_method() in main.o
  "boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite()", referenced from:
      init_unit_test_suite(int, char**) in main.o
  "boost::unit_test::test_case::test_case(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> const&)", referenced from:
      boost::unit_test::make_test_case(boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>) in main.o
  "boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(boost::unit_test::test_case*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main.o
  "boost::unit_test::ut_detail::normalize_test_case_name(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)", referenced from:
      boost::unit_test::make_test_case(boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>) in main.o
  "vtable for boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t", referenced from:
      boost::unit_test::unit_test_log_t::unit_test_log_t() in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Including some of the errors would be helpful so we know which symbols are undefined.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I'm in the same predicament. Was using the boost.framework (1.53.0) based on a script by Peter Goodliffe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add whichever library those functions depend on via "Link Binary With Libraries" in the Build Phases of your Project. However, this then brings up the dreaded EXC_BAD_ACCESS you can read about elsewhere on Stack.